# Inefficient JavaScript Algorithm, How do I make the following code more efficient?

Tags: javascript

**Problem Statement:** Given two arrays **a** and **b** write a function comp(**a, b**) (compSame(**a, b**) in Clojure) that checks whether the two arrays have the "same" elements, with the same multiplicities. "Same" means, here, that the elements in **b** are the elements in **a** squared, regardless of the order.

**My Solution:**

```
function comp(array1, array2){

  var test;

  if( array1.length <= 0 || array2.length <= 0 || array1 == null || array2 == null || array2.length != array1.length || array1==undefined || array2==undefined){
    return false;
  }else{
    for(i=0; i<array2.length; i++){
      for(j=0; j<array1.length; j++){
        if(array2[i] === Math.pow(array1[j],2)){
          test = true;
          break;
        }else{
          test = false;
        }
      }
      if(test==false)
        return false;
    }

    if(test === true)
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
}
```

Also any constructive criticism about the code is appreciated as I'm still just a wookie so always looking to improve.

**Test Example:**

```
var a1 = [80, 2, 65, 68];
var a2 = [6401, 4, 4225, 4624];
```

For the end result all I want is for true to be returned if true and likewise for false. The program solves all the test cases however it times out.

Comment: negative array length?

Comment: One quick thing that sticks out is you're checking `array1.length` before checking `array1 == null`. If the latter is ever true then running the former will produce an error.

Comment: please add some arrays for testing and the wanted result as well.

Comment: `if (test === true) return true; else return false;` can be simplified to: `return test === true;`

Comment: Could you provide some test data?

Comment: @Juan just return test;

Comment: Even better! @Ursache! thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. As it currently stands, this is not a good, specific question for Stackoverflow. This may be a better question for [Code Review Stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Please review their [guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and consider migrating your question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my code

```
function comp(arr1, arr2)
{
    // make sure the arrays are set and are of equal length (if not they obivously don't match)
    if(arr1 == null || arr2 == null || arr1.length != arr2.length)
        return false;
    // sort arrays
    var intSorter = function(a,b){return a-b;};
    arr1.sort(intSorter);
    arr2.sort(intSorter);
    for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++)
    {
        var v = arr1[i];
        // if square of value in arr1 does not equal the value in arr2, arrays don't match
        if(v*v!=arr2[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
// test it!
console.info(comp([2,6,3,8,4,5], [25,64,16,36,4,9]));
console.info(comp([2,6,3,8,4,5], [25,64,17,36,4,9]));
console.info(comp([2,6,3,8,4,5], [25,64,16,36,4,9,9]));
```

Prints true, false, false

I'm not calculating all squares first as a minor optimization, and i use a "custom" `intSorter` because JavaScript sorts numbers as strings, so 4 ends up after 36 ('3' is before '4')

About your code, you don't need a `test` variable, just use `return` whenever you know the function result, and don't use `pow()` for small values as it uses loops and may be more pricy than if you do it `v*v` as I did.

Comment: Thank you this worked and for the extra input. I wasn't even aware that you had to use a compareFunction since `sort( )` by default sorts as strings.

Answer (score 1):

In words:

1. Square the first array
2. Sort the first array
3. Sort the second array.
4. Now if any element does not match the corresponding element in the other array, there is no match.
5. otherwise they match

In code:

```
function comp(array1, array2){

    var test;

    if( !array1 || !array2 ){
        return false;
    }

    if ( array1.length != array2.length ){
        return false;
    }

    // first squre the array
    array1_squared = array1.map( function( val ){ return Math.pow( val, 2 ); } );

    // then sort both arrays
    array1_squared.sort()
    array2.sort()

    // then compare
    for ( var i=0 ; i < array1_squared.length ; i+= 1 ){
        if ( array1_squared[i] != array2[i] ) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

More details, because:

Conceptually, I think this is easier to follow.  One difference is I do the squaring outside of the loop.  You are doing your square inside your loop, which means you are squaring length^2 times, instead of length times.  That makes for some wasted CPU cycles.  Also, you end up looping over your array while looping over your array, which gives length**2 loop executions.  Comparatively, sorting is fairly fast and then it lets us get the actual answer with just one loop.

Comment: You created `array1_squared` but never used it :)

Comment: Yeah just changed `array1.sort() to array1_squared.sort()` still receiving incorrect answer though going through it now.

Comment: Thanks for catching that!  @Dragorn421 caught an important detail too: sort operates on strings, not numbers.  That might be the issue.  Try out his code and see if that does it: he uses essentially the same algorithm otherwise.

Comment: Thanks @ConorMancone! Yep added the `intSorter()` function and worked perfect!